# PHP Unix timestamp conversions out by one hour on one day

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I'm working on an existing website which uses Unix timestamps for saving date/time information (as an `INT UNSIGNED` column in MySQL).

If a user enters a date of 26th March 2017 with any time (the start of British Summer Time, when UK clocks go forward by an hour), when this is saved to the database and then extracted and displayed using `date`, the time shown is one hour greater than that entered by the user. For example, `2017-03-26 20:00:00` when saved becomes `2017-03-26 21:00:00` when displayed. However, this only happens for 26th March 2017 - dates before and after show the same time as entered by the user.

I could understand if this was happening for every day after 26th March but I have no idea why it would only happen on one day. The site didn't have this problem last year either at the beginning or end of British Summer Time.

The default timezone is set to Europe/London (using `date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');`) in a file which is included on every page and `phpinfo` also shows Europe/London as the default timezone.

The server time is correct and the `date` command gives me: `Fri 17 Mar 08:55:13 GMT 2017`.

The server has recently been upgraded which resulted in a version bump from PHP 5.3.x to 5.6.x so that is the only thing I can think of which may have caused this issue.

Is there anything I can do to resolve this, apart from using DATETIME fields (a longer term goal, but not something that can be done in a few days) or subtracting 3600 seconds from timestamps if their date is 26/03/2017 (gets very messy and there are too many places where timestamps are used for that to be practical).

Comment: Why not use a column of Timestamp data type as you want to store Timestamps?

Comment: I don't want to store timestamps, I want to store dates + times (ideally). The other problem with Unix timestamps and MySQL's TIMESTAMP data type is that they only run to 2038, so have about 20 years left.

But as I said, it's not practical to rewrite the database + application in a few days.

Comment: Its a fairly often asked question. Try a search for `summer time` and read some of the other answers. Not sure if this applies when using INT column for timestamps but MYSQL stores DATE/DATETIME/TIMESTAMP in UTC which is not affected by summer/winter time.

Comment: I'm aware it's a frequently asked question, but I can't find any which have this behaviour on a single day, nor where it has just started happening.

Comment: @pwaring and how exactly do you save it into the database? using `strtotime`?

Comment: Effectively yes. We have a small wrapper function to convert UK to ISO dates (otherwise PHP gets confused and thinks 01/02 is the 2nd Jan) and then into `strtotime`.

Comment: and may I ask what is the output of your conversion function for `2017-03-26 20:00:00`?

Comment: The conversion function only swaps the date components around - if you provide `26/03/2017` it will return `2017-03-26`. It's effectively `explode('/')` followed by an array reversal and then `join('-')`. It doesn't take the time as an argument.

Comment: I see, I was more interested in the timestamp it produces to check whether the "shift" occurs during saving or not...